# Can I install Ubuntu 32 bit in a 64 bit machine?

Tags: installation, wubi, 64-bit, windows-8, 32-bit

I have a Windows 8 64 bit machine (Asus N56VJ) and I was asked to install a 32 bit Linux OS at the university for a programming course.

The main problem is that I'm not able to boot from CD (already downloaded and burned Ubuntu in the CD) and if I try Wubi it will install the 64 bit version. I also tried with a program called `easyBCD` using the Wubi disk image but it still doesn't work.

If any of you know how I can fix this I'll be in your debt! Thank you very much!

Comment: That Windows is 64-bit (or that the architecture is 64-bit) does not imply that a 32-bit OS cannot be installed, at least not in the present. Please read [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/159545).

Comment: there is no real reason to install Ubuntu 32-bit or 64-bit for a specific program, both versions will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can install 32 bit Ubuntu on a 64 bit machine.

**There is one exception.**

If you have a machine preinstalled with Windows 8, you cannot easily install 32 bit Ubuntu.

**Options**

1. Install virtual box in Windows and install 32 bit Ubuntu in it.
2. Remove Windows. Change UEFI to BIOS legacy mode. Install Ubuntu.
3. Remove Windows. Change UEFI to BIOS legacy mode. Reinstall Windows. Install Ubuntu side by side.

Hope this helps